# Shell Script or command to Remove all Text Between a start character and end character in Entire Directory

Tags: php, linux, shell, command-line, comments

Looking for an easy way to remove all of my TODO: Comments throughout an entire directory of scripts.

If I have:

```
/*
TODO: Some text here
Some more Here
Some more Here
*/
```

I want to delete the /* Everything in Between and */
Not a huge deal, just wondering for decreasing file sizes

Comment: And have looked on your favorite search engine and read PowerShell documentation ? As you say shouldn't be a big deal.

Comment: Linux..didn't specify

Comment: And yes, I have looked through the hundreds of answers that break code.  Thanks for looking though :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use Bash (sed?) to remove a multiline /\* ... \*/ style comment containing specific text (regex)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20051308/use-bash-sed-to-remove-a-multiline-style-comment-containing-specifi)

Comment: Surely looked but apparently not enough...

Comment: Please avoid *"Give me the codez"* questions. Instead show the script you are working on and state where the problem is. Also see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/608639)

Comment: Last time I posted code, people complained it was too long.  Thank you for pointing that out @Zlemini  I must have overlooked that after my 30 hour coding binge.

Comment: Appreciate the argumentativeness @NPE

Comment: easy to do in php, I just wrote one to extract a single table from a large MySQL dump.  Same Idea.

Comment: Thank you, Ill look into that as well.  RegEx can cause problems if formatting isn't pretty. @ArtisticPhoenix

Comment: Who said anything about Regex?  https://github.com/ArtisticPhoenix/MISC/blob/master/extract_table/index.php  If you look at the bottom, there is little or no regex in it.  You may need some to account for the `\s/*` occasional space. but whatever.  It reads and writes Line for Line, you can read your PHP file one line at a time, then when you hit `/*` check the next line for `@todo` if it's present don't write until you hit `*/` simple.

Comment: I ran that against a `36GB` sql dump and pulled out `120 some MB` of data.  It was some old billing data off our server from 2 years ago.  Took about 5 minutes to run.

Comment: The link above was a sed command.  Mixed results in the past

Comment: That script looks like what I need as a solid jumping off point, I appreciate it.  @ArtisticPhoenix

Answer (score 0):

Here is something to start with:

```
$file = 'somefile.php';

$f = fopen($file,'r');
$temp = dirname($file).'/temp.php';
print_r($temp);
$t = fopen($temp, 'w');

$mode = 'write';
$buffer = [];
while($line=fgets($f)){
    print_r($mode."\n");
    switch($mode){
        case 'write':
            if(preg_match('/^\s*\/\\*/', $line)){
                $buffer[] = $line;
                $mode = 'comment';
            }else{
                fputs($t,$line);
            }
        break;
        case 'comment': 
            if(preg_match('/^\s*\\**\s*@TODO/i', $line)){
                $buffer = [];
                $mode = 'skip';
            }else if(preg_match('/^\s*\\*\//', $line)){
                fwrite($t,implode("", $buffer));
                $buffer = [];
                fputs($t,$line);
                $mode = 'write';
            }else{
                $buffer[] = $line;
            }
        break;
        case 'skip':
            if(preg_match('/^\s*\\*\//', $line)){
                $mode = 'write';
            }
        break;
    }
}
/*
fclose($t);
fclose($f);
rename($temp, $file);
*/
```

I tested it against this file

```
<?php
$var= "foo";

/*
 @todo hello
 some other shuff
 */



/**
 * 
 * @author Me
 *
 */
class someclass{



}
```

This was the stuff in `temp.php`

```
<?php
$var= "foo";




/**
 * 
 * @author Me
 *
 */
class someclass{



}
```

hope it helps.  I would probably back up your files before attempting this.

**UPDATE**

Had to fix a couple minor things so it would skip comments without `@todo`.  The rest you can probably work out fairly easily.

The regex is only there to account for spaces or comments that are like this

```
/*
* @todo
*/
```

This `\\*` becomes `\*` for the regex engine that then becomes a literal `*`.

So this one `\s*\/\\*`

- `\s*` - none or more spaces
- `\/` - the `/` literally
- `\\*` - the `*` literally

Or in English the `/*` open comment tag.

I mention this because the regex is tricky, but you probably have spaces and other stuff in there, probably every `@todo` isn't the very first thing on the line.

Doing it like this, you get to handle each line on it's own, it simplifies things and more importantly increases the matching accuracy.